# How to move window/stage using clutter_actor_animate?

Tags: c, clutter

> How to animate or move window using clutter_actor_animate? Here's my code and it didn't work.

```
clutter_init(&argc, &argv);
ClutterActor stageColor = {0,0,0,255};
ClutterActor *stage = clutter_stage_get_default();
clutter_actor_set_size(stage,512,512);
clutter_stage_set_color(CLUTTER_STAGE(stage),&stage_color);
clutter_actor_animate(stage,CLUTTER_LINEAR, 20000,"x",2500.0,"y",100.0,NULL);
```

> By the way im using clutter1.0.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cannot animate the stage position.

there are actually two reasons for this:

- the position of the Stage in the scene graph is defined to always be (0, 0), as the Stage is the top-level actor inside the graph.
- the position of the window that contains the Stage is owned by the windowing system on the platform being used by Clutter.

this means that you should be using the platform's own API to change the position of the window that contains the Stage.

Comment: ah ok i thought i can move the window... thanks for the information ebassi, because i can't use the move effect, i tried the ClutterOffscreenEffect and ClutterBlurEffect for stage but it doesn't work, any suggestion i could use to add effect for my stage?